# What was the end conclusion for the movie The Man From Earth

Tags: the-man-from-earth

[The Man From Earth (2007)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0756683/) was really a good movie but what I quite didn't understand the end, why does Dr. Gruber die at the end and did it prove that John was God?

Comment: Professor Oldman doesn't die; are you thinking of Dr. Gruber?

Comment: This might receive a more effusive response here; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Roger yes I mean Dr Gruber . . why he dies

Comment: I recently watched this and got curious. Buddha reportedly died around 400 BC in Kushinagar. This is approx 3000 miles from Jerusalem, "as the crow flies". Our cave man said he moved every 10 or so years to avoid detection. That means he would have moved 40 times from Buddha's death to Jesus' birth, with an average distance of 75 miles. That's a pretty safe distance while still being feasible to cover, even on foot. Hmm...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dr. Gruber died of a heart attack after the shock of learning...

> ...that John Oldman is his father.

This does nothing to prove that John is God. It does lend a small amount of credence to John's story, since he knew details about Dr. Gruber's father. However, John only led the group to believe that he was the *inspiration* for the story of Jesus, not that he was in any way God.

Comment: being an inspiration for story of Jesus, does that mean he was Jesus ?

Comment: @Arjuna Yes, according to John Oldman's account of history, he was the man written about in the new testament.

Comment: John never claimed in entire movie that he is God. Through his story, he indirectly said he was Jesus and imparted his knowledge which he gained from Buddha in India. Biblical people started to see him as a messenger and later "Son of God". Also, it was totally co incidental that Dr. Gruber was over hearing John's talk. So, yes, John was Son of God and he was not playing around.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I think of the end :
The girl ( Sandy ) asked John a deliberate question at perfect timing to exploit the heart medical condition weakness of the psychology professor Freud.
I thought that this " question was even worth asking ? "  as its answer provides no good information to the questioner. 
That's why I thought it as a deliberate question like she was working with him so he can approve of her moving with him as she wants cause she loves him. 
Her statement to the john when the professor died: " you have never seen old grown boy death " also reflect the story been made up. 
In the end, she moves towards to his car as he accepts her observation and help and ready to take her with him. 
The psychology professor was a growing threat as he wants to examine the John.
There were some other hints also.
But the question arises:" Why he made up the story? ".